# Select a row on mouse click in gridview

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

I have a problem, I want to select a row in gridview on mouse click.

My code is this :

```
protected void PeopleGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";

            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvdetails, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }
```

it is not working. i don't know why?

plz suggest me regarding that.

"Thanks"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the tutorial about [ASP.Net select row in gridview](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/01/25/asp-net-selecting-a-row-in-a-gridview.aspx)
In ASPX page under GridView tag add:

```
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Orange" />
```

In code behind try the following:

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer) 
{ 
    foreach (GridViewRow row in PeopleGridView.Rows) { 
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) { 
            row.Attributes["onmouseover"] =  
               "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"; 
            row.Attributes["onmouseout"] =  
               "this.style.textDecoration='none';"; 
            // Set the last parameter to True 
            // to register for event validation. 
            row.Attributes["onclick"] =  
             ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(PeopleGridView, 
                "Select$" + row.DataItemIndex, true); 
        } 
    } 
    base.Render(writer); 
}
```

You can then catch this event using the RowCommand (something like).

```
private void PeopleGridView_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.CommandName == "Select") { 
        // Get the list of customers from the session  
        List<Customer> customerList = 
                 Session["Customers"] as List<Customer>;

         Debug.WriteLine(customerList[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].LastName);
    } 
}
```