# how edit, delete, add gridview rows without using command buttons C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I delete, edit and add rows in a gridview with 3 buttons out of it for deleting, editing and adding rows in C# asp.net and refresh grid after changing?
I don't want to use the command buttons of the gridview that is repeated in every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the row some how in order for the code to know which row to delete or edit. Then you can grab the the content of that row on `GridView1_SelectionChanged` in order to delete or update it.

**Edit:**
Here is what to do:
1. Drag a gridview and a textbox to page.
2. Populate gridview
3. Override Render

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                row.Attributes["onclick"] =ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1,
            "Select$" + row.DataItemIndex, true);
            }
        }
        base.Render(writer); 
    }
```

4) In `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
//retrieve the id for selected row
int id=int.Parse(GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());
GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
TextBox1.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
```

Now you can easily customize this simple example up to your taste.

**Edit 2:**
Specify the Id as DataKeyName in gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id"
                onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Check the updated `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` to see how to retrieve the id for selected row.

Comment: How can I get selected row ? when I click on row it doesn't select. My gridview is shown same table.

Comment: don't expect asp.net gridview to behave like winforms datagrid .. Here is a solution which you can try to select the row on click [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314215/select-a-row-on-mouse-click-in-gridview]

Comment: thx, but it doesn't work.my grid has 4 data row, when i set breakpoint at onclick in render(), it falls in loop 4 time and index get 0 to 3 and SelectedStyleRow doesn't affect on selected row.

Comment: thx @ZedBee for helpfull answer, it is work by TEXTBOX, but i when i add this code '<asp:TemplateField ><ItemTemplate ><asp:HiddenField Value="<%#Eval("Id")%>" id="hidIsActive" runat="server" /></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>', when i get the value of this field by ' TextBox1.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;' it is empty and doesn't show the id of row. how can I get this for sending to sp?

Comment: Why are you putting the id in a hidden field and not as DataKeyNames

Comment: thx for helping @ZedBee, I used this code 'TextBox1.Text = NewsGridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();' and solved it.